# Calling formControl setValue deselects mat-chip-list

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have an mat-chip-list input field. The chips are of `selected` style. I notice that whenever I call `setValue()` one the field form control, the chips are unselected. Any way to prevent this behavior?

Before: [image]
After: [image: m]

```
  <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="width-100-percent">
    <mat-label>Assigned Entities</mat-label>
    <mat-chip-list #entityChipList>
      <mat-chip selected  *ngFor="let entityId of entityIds; let idx = index"
                           (removed)="removeEntity(idx)">
        {{entityId}}
        <mat-icon matChipRemove>cancel</mat-icon>
      </mat-chip>
      <input #entityInput name="entity" placeholder="Add new entity" formControlName="entityInput"
             [matAutocomplete]="auto"
             [matChipInputFor]="entityChipList"
             [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeyCodes"
             (matChipInputTokenEnd)="add($event)"/>
    </mat-chip-list>
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="selected($event)">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let entityInfo of filteredEntityInfos | async" [value]="entityInfo">
        {{entityInfo.entityName}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: I'm facing exactly the same issue. Probably because the selected option is of type object instead of string.